# Select start and end of a RegEx

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble naming this question, and it feels like it's something I *should have* found myself, but I'm too dumb it seems. RegEx is still incredibly complicated to me, so please don't be too harsh to me.

Basically, I have a huge list of text of which I need to extract certain word sections. I know the mask around the word, but I obviously only need the word itself. Let me try to give you a simple example:

```
<b>Name1</b>
<i>Name2</i>
<u>Name3</u>
```

I can clearly see the things I want are all surrounded by <> tags. My approach was always to find the entire string and then simply do a plain replace to get rid of these extra characters.

```
<\w>{1}\w+<\/\w>{1}
string.replace("<b>","");
string.replace("</b>","");
... and so on.
```

However, something just feels wrong about it. Like, incredibly wrong. Can't I just directly say in my RegEx search what exactly I'm looking for? Like:

```
<\w>{1}START\w+END<\/\w>{1}
```

Does something like this exist?

(This is a general question, not a specific problem, so please don't provide alternate workarounds or something. I've had this problem many, many times already, and I'm fed up with solving it with this hackish way.)

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions. Use something like [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com).

Comment: This isn't about HTML, this was just a simple example because I couldn't think of anything better.

Comment: What flavor of regex (what environment, programming language)? Maybe what you want is capture groups `()`.

Comment: No specific enviornment or language. With "general" I mean I've encountered this in Visual Basic, JavaScript, and PHP already.

Comment: @user3216060 It's quite unclear what you want, for example what's the expected ouput ? An extremely simple regex would be [`<([a-zA-Z]+)>(.*?)<\/\1>`](http://regex101.com/r/rR0wE6). This doesn't account for nested tags nor tags with attributes.

Comment: So basically, you put the stuff you want as output in ()?

Answer (score 1):

A regex like `(?!<\w>)\w+(?=<\/\w>)` might be what you are looking for. See example here [regextester](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%3F!%3C%5Cw%3E%29%5Cw%2B%28%3F%3D%3C%5C%2F%5Cw%3E%29&input=%3Cb%3EName1%3C%2Fb%3E%0A%3Ci%3EName2%3C%2Fi%3E%0A%3Cu%3EName3%3C%2Fu%3E)

Comment: Seems to work, although I'm not sure what this does or even is. Gah, so much to learn...

Comment: Basically `(?!<\w>)` says only match something that has `<\w>` right before it. Likewise, `(?=<\/\w>)` will only allow a match on something that has `<\/\w>` right after it. I personally find that [regexper](http://www.regexper.com/#(%3F!%3C%5Cw%3E)%5Cw%2B(%3F%3D%3C%5C%2F%5Cw%3E)) is a great tool for learning this kind of thing.

Comment: @dvnrrs that is true. It just depends on what you are trying to do, and how your mind works. For me this method is easier conceptually, if not the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

How about `<[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/[^>]+>`?  It'll match the whole "tag", but it'll only capture what's between the tags...